# importing several text files into R

Tags: r, import

I have four folders which contain text files (tab delimited) of the same names, I would like to import all of these text files into a data.frame. For example:

```
TopFolder = "G:\\University" 
SubFolder = list.files(TopFolder)
#find the name of the folders in the current directory
DateTime = rbind(read.table(paste(TopFolder,SubFolder[1],"Data.txt",sep = "\\"),sep="\t"),
                read.table(paste(TopFolder,SubFolder[2],"Data.txt",sep = "\\"),sep="\t"),
                 read.table(paste(TopFolder,SubFolder[3],"Data.txt",sep = "\\"),sep="\t"),
                 read.table(paste(TopFolder,SubFolder[4],"Data.txt",sep = "\\"),sep="\t"))
```

This example works fine, although I was hoping of using a loop or some other function to generate this variable without having to import all of the files individually. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
lf = list.files(path = "G:\\University", pattern = "Data.txt", 
                full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)

library(plyr)
DateTime = ldply(lf, read.table, sep = "\t")
```

Comment: That works great. How could this be altered to import several text files. Say if I wanted to first import Data.txt but then wanted to import Data2.txt which is stored in the same way as Data.txt (i.e in different folders)?

Comment: you can modify the pattern in `list.files` with a suitable regular expression, see `?regex`